70s / 80s thriller about a warhead that fell down accidentally
Many years ago, I watched a movie and can't find it again. Maybe you can help! :)
In the movie a bomb, missile, warhead or something like that crashes into a building or its roof construction. This might have happened due to an airplane accident or a technical malfunction in the airplane cargo chute.
After the warhead / bomb came down, it poses the threat it might explode sooner or later. As far as I recall, it was leaking acid or something like that.
The missile might have been named M5 or M52 or something similar. (Not sure! I might mix this from some other movie.)
I guess the movie (genre: probably thriller) was from the 70s or 80s. It's atmosphere or appearance felt similar to War Games, the Airport series and movies like that. It was a color film, it was a live action movie (no cartoon) and it was exciting.

Maybe take a look at this list to see if any of them are familiar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_about_nuclear_issues

Was the entire (or bulk of the) plot about defusing/removing the warhead?

Refer here for knowing how to merge account.
